# sidebarPanel shrinks when add css "style = position: fixed;"

Tags: r, shiny

I need to have a fixed sidebarPanel, but I am having problems when add `style = 'position: fixed;'`. When I add the style, the sidebarPanel shrinks. 
The code (with `style = 'position: fixed;'`) below. The image shows the result without and with the `style = 'position: fixed;'` How can I make it that the sibarPanel doesn't shrink?

```
# User interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2, 
                 style='position: fixed;',
                 uiOutput("countryList")),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot1"),
      plotOutput("distPlot2"),
      plotOutput("distPlot3"))))
# Server logic  
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$countryList <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("countryName", "Country",
                   choices = c('Austria', 'The United Kingdom'))})
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100))})
  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(200))})
  output$distPlot3 <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(300))})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: The image with and without <code>style = 'position: fixed;'</code>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the way:

```
library(shiny)
# User interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(class = "row",
      div(class = "col-sm-4", 
          tags$form(class = "well col-sm-4", `data-spy` = "affix", # this is the sidebar
              uiOutput("countryList")
          )
      ), 
      div(class = "col-sm-8", # this is the main panel
          plotOutput("distPlot1"),
          plotOutput("distPlot2"),
          plotOutput("distPlot3")
      )
  )
)

# Server logic  
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$countryList <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("countryName", "Country",
                   choices = c('Austria', 'The United Kingdom'))})
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100))})
  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(200))})
  output$distPlot3 <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(300))})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```